# How can I recover the lost data from the deleted ntfs partition?

Tags: lubuntu

I use Windows 7 as well as Lubuntu 14.10 OS on my desktop PC. Yesterday, I was doing the repartition process of my 160 GB SATA HDD from Lubuntu bootable CD. I accidentally deleted some of the Windows 7 partitions (ntfs partitions) which contains my whole Software setups and some good Mp3 music files.

I want to recover the whole data from the HDD.

Can you please tell me how can I do this process using the photorec tool in Lubuntu terminal?

NB: I expect the step by step process from you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of options, here is a wonderful guide:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Typically, `photorec` is my goto tool.